# Laravel Eloquent 'LIKE' not working as expected

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query using where statement with 'LIKE', but seems like it is not returning the desired result

my database has a product table, and my query is

```
Product::where('sku', 'like', "%"."A47ROD01"."%")->get()
```

while the sku stored in the database is A47ROD

Comment: Did you try a raw query? `SELECT * FROM products WHERE sku LIKE '%A47ROD01%';` - That won't return any results, since `A47ROD` is not like `A47ROD01`. This seems to be working just fine...

Comment: That works as expected. `%A47ROD01%` will not match `A47ROD`. It will match things like `A47ROD01000`, `000A47ROD01` or `000A47ROD01000`.

Comment: Facinating waste of time `"%"."A47ROD01"."%"` why not put that all in ONE String Literal

Comment: `LIKE` does not mean "quite similar to" in the way you'd mean in plain English. `A47ROD` is *like* `A47ROD01`, but not to SQL.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, You should know that many people simplify their code example when posting to Stack Overflow. The middle part may be a variable in the real code.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yup, and in doing so often add additional errors or at least confusion for us to circumnavigate.

Comment: Sometimes, but in this case it is harmless and it takes no effort to understand that code.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, you want to search with a LIKE `A47ROD`, but your request says you must have at least `A47ROD01` to find a result, that part `A47ROD**01**` not match your result.

You need to do

```
Product::where('sku', 'like', "%A47ROD%")->get()
```

Comment: Facinating waste of time `"%"."A47ROD01"."%"` why not put that all in ONE String Literal